# Get property of php object in bootstrap table

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, object

i have a PHP object array called "arregloRegalos" from the class "Regalo". I use that array to create a table with a For and bootstrap.

this is the code to create the Table:

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<count($arregloRegalos);$i++)
    {
?>

<div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
       <img class="media-object" src="../PaginaRestaurante/imagenes/dogo-chico.jpg" >
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">

       <h5 class="media-heading">
          <?php echo $arregloRegalos[$i]->restaurante; ?>
       </h5>
       <div class="col-md-10">
          <label>
             <?php echo $arregloRegalos[$i]->descripcion; ?> 
          </label>

       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cobrar regalo!</button>
       </div>
    </div>

 </div>
 <?php 
     }
  ?>
```

And this is my PHP class REGALO

```
class Regalo {

    //put your code here
    public $id="";
    public $restaurante="";
    public $descripcion="";

    function __construct($id,$restaurante,$descripcion) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->restaurante=$restaurante;
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
    } 
}
```

In the table i have a column of buttons, now i want to know the id of the object in the php Array from the row of the button clicked, any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show me the output of your array using echo "<pre>"; print_r($arregloRegalos);

Answer (score 0):

you can ues property of button to  saving the object'id :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="<?php echo $arregloRegalos[$i]->$id;?>">Cobrar regalo!</button>
```